# Could not access Kubernetes Ingress

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, azure-aks, nginx-ingress

I am trying to run a mlflow server on Azure Kubernetes. I can access the server when attaching service to deployment as a Load Balancer. However, when I am trying to access the server using ingress it can't access it. However, when running the ingress public IP on port 80 I get Nginx server error `404 not found`, which is expected but when running on mlflow server 5000 it is timed out.

Below are the manifest files for the deployment, Load Balancer service and Ingress.

**Deployment:**

```
    apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      name: mlflow-deployment
      labels:
        app: mlflow
    spec:
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          app: mlflow
      replicas: 1
      template:
        metadata:
          labels:
            app: mlflow
        spec:
          containers:
            - name: mlflow
              image: rjtshrm/mlflow:latest
              args: ["--backend-store-uri", "postgresql://psql:_Reply2022@mlflopgsql.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/postgres?sslmode=require", "--default-artifact-root", "wasbs://mlflow@mlflowsmodeltorage.blob.core.windows.net", "--host", "0.0.0.0"]
              ports:
                - containerPort: 5000
```

**Service: Load Balancer**

```
    apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      name: mlflow
      labels:
        app: mlflow
    spec:
      selector:
        app: mlflow
      type: LoadBalancer
      ports:
        - port: 5000
          targetPort: 5000
```

**Ingress:**

```
    apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
    kind: Ingress
    metadata:
      name: mlflow-server-ingress
      annotations:
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/ssl-redirect: "false"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/use-regex: "true"
        nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2
    spec:
      ingressClassName: mlflow-server-ingress
      rules:
        - http:
            paths:
              - path: /(.*)
                pathType: Prefix
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: mlflow
                    port:
                      number: 5000
```

Also, to install the Ingress controller I did the steps below.

```
    helm repo add ingress-nginx https://kubernetes.github.io/ingress-nginx
    helm repo update
    helm install ingress-nginx ingress-nginx/ingress-nginx  --namespace default   --set controller.service.annotations."service\.beta\.kubernetes\.io/azure-load-balancer-health-probe-request-path"=/healthz
```

Below it can be seen the services running in default namespace. The ingress-nginx-controller has a public IP which I can access on port 80 and get this error message `404 not found`. Then for the Load Balancer, I can access the server with external IP on port 5000.
[Can be seen in the image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e1XU0.png)

After applying the Ingress yaml file when I'm trying to access the ingress-nginx-controller on port 5000, the site can't be reached. the logs of ingress-nginx-controller [here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hsNmm.png)

PS: I have added the image and its args in the deployment file. It is public image with test Database credentials so that the whole thing can be tested.

Answer (score 1):

Is your `.spec.ingressClassName` field correct? I see you deployed nginx ingress controller.

Comment: Thanks, yes it was wrong. It has to be "nginx".

Answer (score 0):

The nginx controller (at least the last time I used it) only listens on 80 and 443. So you can't use port 5000 on the ingress controller unless you set it via the helm chart values.

You *can* still use port 5000 on the service behind the ingress -- i.e. you are connecting nginx port 80/443 to your service's port 5000